# Angular - UI Router - HTML5 Mode - WebForms

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, html, webforms, angular-ui-router

I have a WebForms project and try to improve it with the AngularJS. I've configured UI-Router on one of my pages and multi-view is currently working as it's intended to. Later on I've tried to exclude hashtag symbol from the url, so I've turned on $locationProvider.html5Mode, however there is a problem in refreshing a page. As I understood reading through answers on the Stackoverflow and others that the problem is that WebForms treat the url modified by UI-Router as a real url that should correspond to a page and I get 404 error. I've tried a bunch of proposed solutions, but it seems to me that they could work only for ASP.Net MVC project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your **Global.asax.cs**

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "url_with_angular_view_postfix", "your_webforms_page_url");
```